# Call method from another class without inheritance and creating an instance

Tags: python, oop

Let's say I have a class `Person` with method `_build_record`, *I don't want this method to be called by the user or can be seen with `dir(Person)`.*

So I created another class `helper` and moved the method `_build_record` as it is, and then calling it in the `Person` class by `helper._build_record(self)` which works fine but **I'm not sure if this is the right approach or if there is an any better approach.**

**This is just an example of what I'm doing, my main class has a lot of methods.**

```py
class helper(object):
    """Helper class for Person."""
    def _build_record(self):
        return { 'name': self.name, 'age': self.age }

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.record = helper._build_record(self)

a = Person('Saad', 100)
print(a.record)
```

Comment: `_build_record` is just a stand-alone function, you don’t need `class helper` for it at all.

Comment: @deceze: you're right I can just have a function `_build_record` but just to keep things organized because there are a lot more methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `self` in `_build_record(self)`should be its class's own instance. But it's expecting some other class's instance so this all looks confusing.

Python provides two ways to call methods of class without creating instance: [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) and [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

Your examples looks like a good use case for `staticmethod`.

```
class helper(object):
    @staticmethod
    def _build_record(person):
        return { 'name': person.name, 'age': person.age }
```

Now it's more clear that `_build_record` expects a person instance.

---

**Update:**

If you want to have access to the class (so that you can call its other methods), you should use `classmethod`. A `classmethod` will receive the current class as the first argument.

```
class helper(object):
    @classmethod
    def _build_record(cls, person):
        # now you can call other methods of the class
        cls.some_other_method()

        return ...
```

`classmethod` and `staticmethod` are called in the same manner.

Comment: Ah you are right `@staticmethod` can be used here, let me test it with my main class.

Comment: Your answer works very well as per the question asked but I really forget to mention that the `helper` class has its own methods which are been called in the `_build_record` method but as there is no `self` parameter it cannot be called with `self`. Everything is getting so confusing I think I've to redesign everything.

Comment: @Saad In that case, you can use `classmethod`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I think that `cls.some_other_method()` needs an argument as it will throw *`missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`* error, assuming `def some_other_method(self):` is a method of `helper` class.

Comment: @Saad All other methods should be either `staticmethod` or `classmethod`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a private method if you have double underscore as its prefix.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __build_record(self):
        return { 'name': self.name, 'age': self.age }

a = Person('Saad', 100)
print(a.__build_record)
```

If you try to call that method you will see the error

```
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute '__build_record'
```

Comment: Yes, but when you print `print(dir(Person))` one can still see it.